# Google Place Report API: app-specific tag

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-place-report

I'm incorporating Google Place Report API into my app:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/report-place

It says I must put in an app-specific tag with my place report:

> An app-specific tag that defines the context of the place report. A
>   typical app can expect to have 1 to 5 tags, corresponding to the
>   difference checkin flows in the app. For example, let's assume your
>   app includes three flows: review a place, add a place, and share a
>   place. You would define three tag codes, one for each of the flows.
>   Note: There are no pre-defined tags. The value of the tags within your
>   application is entirely up to you. The tags provide a useful way of
>   identifying the place reports from each type of call made by your app.

Then it goes and says it is not possible to retrieve the report once it is sent:

> It's not possible to retrieve the report later, and the report is not
>   linked to the user's account.

What is the point of defining a tag in the report if the developer can not extract the report afterwards. By not being able to extract the report afterwards, this means we cannot use it for our development processes.

What exactly does google use the tags for? Do they need it for their processes to split what was submitted into appropriate categories?

Example from google:

```
public static final String PLACEREPORT_REVIEW = "review";
...
final PlaceReport report = PlaceReport.create(placeId, PLACEREPORT_REVIEW);
Places.PlaceDetectionApi.reportDeviceAtPlace(mGoogleApiClient, report)
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(Status status) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Report place result result: " + status.toString());
  }
});
```